# Is the resulting vector part of row/column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Per Wikipedia: In linear algebra, the column space (also called the range or image) of a matrix A is the span (set of all possible linear combinations) of its column vectors.

Wiki also gives an example:

[image]

Is the vector (c1, c2, 2c1) part of the column space as well?  Or just the original column vectors and their respective scalars?  Like what exactly is included in the column space - I know it's all possible linear combinations.  Is it the entire expression itself?

Comment: for given $c_1$ and $c_2$, $\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\2c_1}$ is a linear combination of the column vectors, so included in the column space

Comment: So in the above example, all three vectors would be included in the "column space"?

Comment: any vector of the form $\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\2c_1}$ is included; e.g., when $c_1=1$ and $c_2=0$, when $c_1=0$ and $c_2=1$, when $c_1=1$ and $c_2=1$, when $c_1=1.4$ and $c_2=-0.3$, etc.

Comment: @confused: Yes $ \pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\2c_1}$ is in column space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any linear combination of the column vectors $\pmatrix{1\\0\\2}$ and $\pmatrix {0\\1\\0}$ is in the column space.

That means $\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\2c_1}$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are any scalars.

This includes $\pmatrix{1\\0\\2}$, $\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$, $\pmatrix{1\\1\\2}$, $\pmatrix{1\\-1\\2}$, and a whole host of others

-- in fact, any vector whose third component is twice its first component.

Comment: Ok thanks, this helps.